# Is it an absorbing state if it does not communicate with other states?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, markov-chains

$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\ 
0 & 0.5 & 0.5
\end{matrix}$$

Given that this is a right transition matrix, would you call the state in the first row, say A, an absorbing state?

An absorbing state requires that it cannot be left, which A fulfills. However, it does not communicate with other states, thus no other state can enter it. So, is it still an absorbing state since the full definition of an absorbing state is that it is a state that **once entered** cannot be left.

Comment: If it were to be entered, then you would never leave. As it happens it can't be entered from anywhere other than itself, but that's no real obstacle. I'd call it absorbing but I would probably comment somewhere that the chain is reducible.

Comment: I would agree that it is an absorbing state.  An alternate definition would be that in the transition matrix, a one exists along the main diagonal in its position.  The matrix itself however is not an absorbing matrix, so it is not an absorbing markov chain.  Neither is it a regular markov chain due to the absorbing state.  As mentioned, though, you can consider two separate markov chains, one for state A, and another for states B and C, which are absorbing and regular respectively.